# passing image path from storage in Laravel failed

Tags: laravel

I have stored my images in storage/app/public/images.
and i have done the storage:link.
now i want to get a path for an image that exists in /images and i want to send it with an API.
i do the below to pass it to HTTP::attach():

```
$path = storage_path('images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_file);
```

and then:

```
$response = Http::attach('new_file', file_get_contents($path))->post('http://localhost/imageresizer/service.php', $sizes);
```

when i dd($path), everything seems OK and i get the path i expect.
but there's the below error when i log::debug:

```
file_get_contents(C:\laragon\www\myblog\storage\images\SVoGGKjERVMYxy9qDciAhgOse9kzQsIuvBg64hjE.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

what's the problem with **file_get_contents** ?

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in `storage/app/public/images`, you'll want to use:

```php
$path = storage_path('app/public/images/' . $new_file);
```

NB the additional `'app/public/'`.